# Core Data lightweight migration - do existing entities have new attributes added to them?

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I have a Core Data managed object model all set up and working in an iOS app, and I'm using NSManagedObject subclasses which are instantiated using `[[MyEntityClass alloc] initWithEntity:description insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];`

I have been reading some tutorials on Core Data migrations to prepare for possible future updates to the app. For the changes I currently envisage for this particular case, I am confident that lightweight migration will be sufficient. I understand that lightweight migration maps the data from the old data model to the new version. But there is one thing I'm not clear in. If the persistent store contains NSManagedObject subclass instances which were created from before the migration, will these objects be modified along with the model to allow them to use the attributes added in the migration?

I'll give an example to make sure I'm being clear about what I'm asking. Lets say I have an entity called, to use the classic example, `Person`. Person has the following attributes:

```
firstname
lastname
```

I create an instance of `Person` called `aPerson` and this is inserted into the persistent store. I can access `aPerson`'s attributes using `aPerson.firstname` and `aPerson.lastname`.

Now I add a `dateofbirth` attribute to the managed object model, so the `Person` entity contains the following attributes:

```
firstname
lastname
dateofbirth
```

Now, what happens if I retrieve `aPerson` from the persistent store and try to access `aPerson.dateofbirth`? Will I get an unrecognised selector error because `aPerson` does not contain the `dateofbirth` attribute due to being created before the addition of that attribute? Or will the lightweight migration add the `dateofbirth` attribute and the accessor methods to all instances of `Person` already in the persistent store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an attribute to a new model version, the attribute must either be optional or you must specify a default value. Otherwise the persistent store saved with the old model would not validate with the new model.

In your example, it does not make sense to specify a default `dateofbirth`, so you would make that attribute optional and cope with it sometimes not being present.

I can’t find explicit documentation on this. You should test migrations very thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's extremely helpful! So, when you say coping with the attribute not being present, would that involve something like `if ([myEntity respondsToSelector:@selector(myMigratedAttributeName)){...}`

Comment: No, methods are on classes, not instances. You read the property and see if it is `nil`.

Comment: `methods are on classes, not instances` - yes, but wouldn't `respondsToSelector:` verify that the property is present on the NSManagedObject subclass? If the entity subclass was created before the data migration would attempting to access the added property just return nil, or would it cause an unrecognised selector exception?

Comment: It would return `nil`. The properties a managed object has come from the attributes of its entity, and the entity is part of the managed object model.

Comment: Ahh ok. I assumed the managed object was stored in its entirety with any properties it has already set up, and so if an 'old' managed object didn't have the added properties  of a newer version of the entity, the app would crash. If it would just return nil then this is fine. Thanks so much for all your help!